# mySQL optimize query for quick fetching

Tags: mysql

I have something like this:

```
SELECT INCOME
FROM PATIENTS
JOIN CASES
ON PATIENT_ID = CASE_PATIENT_ID
WHERE YEAR(DATE_OF_BIRTH) = '1955' AND YEAR(CASE_DATE)>'2000'
GROUP BY INCOME
```

My problem is that both tables (PATIENTS and CASES) have millions of rows and year() disables my indexes and makes my query very very slow.

How can I optimize it in order to run faster? (I tried using a nested SELECT in order to extract only the dates I want but it returns nothing).

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Since my question may look a bit vague, plz help me optimize the following code because it gets stuck at fetching.

```
    select round(avg(INCOME_PER_MONTH),2) as Average_Income,
case
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 < 15 then "Very Severly Underweight"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 15 and 16 then "Severly Underweight"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 16.1 and 18.5 then "Underweight"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 18.6 and 25 then "Normal (healthy weight)"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 25.1 and 30 then "Overweight"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 30.1 and 35 then "Obese Class I"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 35.1 and 40 then "Obese Class II"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 > 40 then "Obese Class III"
end
as BMI,
WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)
from PATIENTS
join CASES
on PATIENT_ID = PAT_ID and PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID = CASES.PAT_ID
where CASES.DATE_OF_CONT  between '2005-01-01' and '2010-12-31'
and PATIENTS.DATE_OF_BIRTH between '1995-01-01' and '1995-12-31'
group by
case
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 < 15 then "Very Severly Underweight"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 15 and 16 then "Severly Underweight"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 16.1 and 18.5 then "Underweight"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 18.6 and 25 then "Normal (healthy weight)"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 25.1 and 30 then "Overweight"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 30.1 and 35 then "Obese Class I"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 between 35.1 and 40 then "Obese Class II"
    when WEIGHT/(HEIGHT*HEIGHT)*10000 > 40 then "Obese Class III"
end
```

All columns have indexes and there are a couple millions of rows in each one of them.

My objective is to show the average income of patients born at a specific year and contacted us between 2005 and 2010.

I hope it proves itself as a proper challenge ;)

Comment: What is the format of the data stored in the `DATE_OF_BIRTH` and `CASE_DATE` columns?  Can you give an example of each?

Comment: A range query will be faster: `date_of_birth BETWEEN '1955-01-01' AND '1955-12-31' AND case_date > '2000-12-31'`

Comment: They are stored as Dates (YY-mm-dd). I try to avoid head on comparison because then it will have to compare 3min by 5mil dates.

Comment: `YY-mm-dd` is not a date in MySQL. They are all stored as `VARCHAR` perhaps? Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE PATIENTS` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE CASES` and add the output to your question.

Comment: PATIENTS : `DATE_OF_BIRTH` date DEFAULT NULL', CASES : `CASE_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL'                                                           I try to use year(DATE) because it will help my code which will accept a 4 digit number as the year of birth.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but this should work:

```
SELECT INCOME
FROM PATIENTS
JOIN CASES
ON PATIENT_ID = CASE_PATIENT_ID
WHERE DATE_OF_BIRTH BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1955', '-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1955', '-12-31'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND 
      CASE_DATE > STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2000', '-12-31'), '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY INCOME
```

Comment: Thank you for you solution but unfortunately when I use ranges it takes an eternity to fetch the data because of the bulk of the rows. I try to find a way to avoid comparing and transforming all DoBs with all CaseDates.

Comment: Do you have indexes on your table? What is the result of EXPLAIN on the query?